on salesforce knowledge object
When the article is in draft status and approval status is not approved, the user click on the publish button it is allowing to publish the article.
My requirement is when user click on publish button it should allow only approval status is Approved or else it should throw error. For this I had written validation rule
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(PublishStatus , "Published"),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Knowledges_Approval_Status__c, "Approved"))
)

I am using this but user able to publish which is not in approved state but its not working.
Any suggestions?
